# Django url pattern error: Reverse for 'chat' with arguments '(1, 2)' not found

Tags: html, django

I've been following [this nifty chat creating tutorial](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@ajmaln/part-2-simple-chat-application-using-djangorestframework) ([git for the nifty tutorial](https://github.com/ajmaln/DRF-Chat)) and was able to get it to work perfectly. However, when I tried implementing it to my project I converted the url in the main project to what I have above and the effects are trickling downward.

I cant' seem to pass in an argument to a url pattern in a .html page. Here's what I got

My main project url.py

```
url(r'^chat/', include("chat.urls",namespace='chat')),
```

My app 'chat's url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', chat_view, name='chats'),
    url(r'^<int:sender>/<int:receiver>/$', message_view, name='chat'),
]
```

The app chat's view

```
def chat_view(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('chat:chats')
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, 'chat/chat.html',
                    {'users': User.objects.exclude(email=request.user.email)})
```

HTML page: chat.html

```
{% for user in users %}
<p>{{ user }}</p>
<a href="{% url 'chat:chat' 1 2 %}" id="user{{ user.id }}" class="collection-item row">
{% endfor %}
```

Error message:

```
Reverse for 'chat' with arguments '(1, 2)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['chat/<int:sender>/<int:receiver>/$']
```

Error occurs when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/ . When I remove the arguments the page pops up.

Anyone have any thoughts on why this is? I tried to take out 'chat' from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Url path types (int, str, slug, etc.) are new feature and available only since Django 2.0 If you are using this version you should use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) instead of `url`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', chat_view, name='chats'),
    path('<int:sender>/<int:receiver>/', message_view, name='chat'),
]
```

Otherwise you need to relpase `int` type to regular expression:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', chat_view, name='chats'),
    url(r'^(?P<sender>\d+)/(?P<receiver>\d+)/$', message_view, name='chat'),
]
```

Comment: That's right! I was working from a tutorial that was Django 2.0 and my project is in Django 1.11. Thanks!